# When printing extra blank paper is sent through! Why?

Tags: vb.net, excel, sqlite, printing

Got this algorithm in VB.net which manipulates and prints an excel document but every time i print i get an extra sheet of paper BEFORE the document i want to print! No extra pages on the excel sheet or anything like that! Can anyone spot the reason why in this code or does anyone know why? Thanks

```
Sub Cmd_PrintClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    'print 1 page
    printDocument.PrinterSettings.Copies = 1
    'print document (see Sub PrintDocumentPrintPage below ...)
    printDocument.Print

End Sub

Sub PrintDocumentPrintPage(sender As Object, e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)

    Dim oApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook = oApp.Workbooks.Add()
    Dim oWS As Excel.Worksheet = CType(oWB.Worksheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)

    Dim oRng1 As Excel.Range
    Dim search As String = ""

    SQLcommand = SQLconnect.CreateCommand
    'Create SQL statement
    SQLcommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Bill_Record WHERE Paid = 'F'"
    'Extract data
    SQLreader = SQLcommand.ExecuteReader()

    While SQLreader.Read()

    search = "" 
    search = SQLreader("Pupil_ID")

    oWB = oApp.Workbooks.Open("F:\Kids Club Database\Kids Club Database v2\Backup\ContactsDatabase\bin\Debug\Bill.xlsx")
    oWS = oWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    oRng1 = oWS.Range("F34")
    oRng1.Value = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(SQLreader("Payment_Due_Date"),10)

    oRng1 = oWS.Range("A19")
    oRng1.Value =  Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(SQLreader("Bill_Date"),10)

    oRng1 = oWS.Range("A13")
    oRng1.Value = SQLreader("Term")

    oRng1 = oWS.Range("C47")
    oRng1.Value = SQLreader("Term")

    oRng1 = oWS.Range("H28")
    oRng1.Value = SQLreader("Total_Term_Cost")

    oRng1 = oWS.Range("C48")
    oRng1.Value = SQLreader("Total_Term_Cost")

    oRng1 = oWS.Range("F22")
    oRng1.Value = SQLreader("Total_Sessions_Monday")

    oRng1 = oWS.Range("H22")
    oRng1.Value = SQLreader("Total_Monday_Cost")

    oRng1 = oWS.Range("F23")
    oRng1.Value = SQLreader("Total_Sessions_Tuesday")

    oRng1 = oWS.Range("H23")
    oRng1.Value = SQLreader("Total_Tuesday_Cost")

    oRng1 = oWS.Range("F24")
    oRng1.Value = SQLreader("Total_Sessions_Wednesday")

    oRng1 = oWS.Range("H24")
    oRng1.Value = SQLreader("Total_Wednesday_Cost")

    oRng1 = oWS.Range("F25")
    oRng1.Value = SQLreader("Total_Sessions_Thursday")

    oRng1 = oWS.Range("H25")
    oRng1.Value = SQLreader("Total_Thursday_Cost")

    oRng1 = oWS.Range("F26")
    oRng1.Value = SQLreader("Total_Sessions_Friday")

    oRng1 = oWS.Range("H26")
    oRng1.Value = SQLreader("Total_Friday_Cost")



    'Clear SQL command buffer
    SQLcommand.Dispose()

    SQLcommand = SQLconnect.CreateCommand
    'Create SQL statement
    SQLcommand.CommandText = "SELECT Pupil_Name, Pupil_Surname, Form_ID FROM Pupil WHERE Pupil_ID = '" & search &"'"
    'Extract data
    SQLreader = SQLcommand.ExecuteReader()

    oRng1 = oWS.Range("A16")
    oRng1.Value = SQLreader("Pupil_Name") & " " & SQLreader("Pupil_Surname")

    oRng1 = oWS.Range("C46")
    oRng1.Value = SQLreader("Pupil_Name") & " " & SQLreader("Pupil_Surname")

    oRng1 = oWS.Range("A17")
    oRng1.Value = SQLreader("Form_ID")

    'Clear SQL command buffer
    SQLcommand.Dispose()

    SQLcommand = SQLconnect.CreateCommand
    'Create SQL statement
    SQLcommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Price"
    'Extract data
    SQLreader = SQLcommand.ExecuteReader()

    oRng1 = oWS.Range("D22")
    oRng1.Value = SQLreader("Price_Monday")

    oRng1 = oWS.Range("D23")
    oRng1.Value = SQLreader("Price_Tuesday")

    oRng1 = oWS.Range("D24")
    oRng1.Value = SQLreader("Price_Wednesday")

    oRng1 = oWS.Range("D25")
    oRng1.Value = SQLreader("Price_Thursday")

    oRng1 = oWS.Range("D26")
    oRng1.Value = SQLreader("Price_Friday")

    'Clear SQL command buffer
    SQLcommand.Dispose()

    oRng1 = Nothing   ' <-- Don't forget!
    oWB.PrintOut()
    oWB.Close()
    oWB = Nothing

    oWS = Nothing
    oApp.Quit()
    oApp = Nothing

    End While

    End Sub
```

Comment: If you take the spreadsheet and do a print preview (just the template without the code), does it show a blank sheet there?

Comment: Tried it and it definatley doesn't have any extra blank pages before or after!

Comment: You are sure `e.HasMorePages = False`?

Comment: I am certain it doesn't have any extra pages! If i print from excel directly only the page on the document comes out of the printer! No blank pages!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change:

```
oWB.PrintOut()
```

To:

```
oWB.PrintOut(From:=1, [To]:=1, Copies:=1, Collate:=False)
```

**Edit**

Also, be sure to set desired [`PageSetup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PageSetup.aspx) (sheet):

```
With oWS.PageSetup
    .Zoom = False
    .PaperSize = XlPaperSize.xlPaperA4
    .Orientation = XlPageOrientation.xlPortrait
    .FitToPagesTall = 1
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
End With
```

**Edit 2**

So why an extra blank page? It's as simple as this. You have placed your excel interop code inside the `PrintPageEvent` of a `PrintDocument`. So the extra page is being printed by the `PrintDocument`.

```
Sub PrintDocumentPrintPage(sender As Object, e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)
    e.Cancel = True '< Do not print
    'YOUR CODE...
End Sub
```

Or move everything to a separate sub and call when needed:

```
Private Sub PrintXLS()
    'YOUR CODE...
End Sub
```

Comment: Put this in system! Still didn't like it!

Comment: Hm... Just for fun, set `.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$A$1"`.

Comment: Try change `oWB.PrintOut` to `oWS.PrintOut`. (From Workbook to Worksheet). Haha, take a look at the section "Example" here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194365.aspx.

Comment: Then  i'm running out of ideas. Oh, wait. I'll update my answer.

Comment: You sir are the most awesome person in the world! Thank you oh so much! That last edit worked perfectly!

Comment: @ZacEvans That's great! :D

Comment: I would upvote your answer too but i don't have enough reputation yet! Sorry!

Answer (score -1):

Dim oWS As Excel.Worksheet = CType(oWB.Worksheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)

I think should be:

Dim oWS As Excel.Worksheet = CType(oWB.Worksheets(0), Excel.Worksheet)

Edit 1:

How about:

Dim oWS As Excel.Worksheet = oWB.Worksheets.Add(New Excel.Worksheet)

I think what is happening is that your adding the worksheet at worksheet position 1 instead of worksheet position 0, so the first worksheet (blank one) is printing first, then the sheet your trying to work with is being printed.

Edit 2:

```
oWB = oApp.Workbooks.Open("F:\Kids Club Database\Kids Club Database v2\Backup\ContactsDatabase\bin\Debug\Bill.xlsx")
oWS = oWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

oRng1 = oWS.Range("F34") ' Put a break point on this line and check the oWB.Worksheets collection and see how many worksheets there are in the collection and make sure the first one is named "Sheet 1"
```